# Java HashMap<String, String> containsKey() fails

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a Java `HashMap<String, String>`. Firstly I populate this map with 100 known string keys. Next I use multiple callables to add random string keys, two thousand keys in total. I also use multiple callables to call HashMap.containsKey() for the 100 known keys. I execute these callables all concurrently, Why do I see many of these containsKey() calls fail? Surely String implements the hashCode() and equals() methods "properly".

What do I need to do to ensure my 100 known keys are always found within the map?

Comment: Are you *adding* to the map concurrently? Bear in mind that `HashMap` isn't thread-safe. Can you show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Looks like some `Callable`s are performing lookups on your `Map` before all the keys are set.

Comment: Yes, I am adding keys in multiple callables, however the 100 known keys are all added "up front", before I start any of the callables

Comment: As @JonSkeet says, you cannot modify a `HashMap` from multiple threads concurrently, nor can you read from a `HashMap` while another thread performs an update.  You will either need to wait until the last items have been added before querying the map, or you will need to use a concurrency-safe map.

Comment: ‎@Hector If you're adding the rest of the keys from multiple threads, HashMap will inevitably malfunction.

Comment: Oh dear, my issue is this hashmap is cached across multiple servers ... So making it a concurrency safe map is going to be tricky. The processing requires new keys are added all the time while I also need to be calling contains key

Comment: Well then, it would be better if you use a proper distribute cache library like ecache or infinispan instead of brewing your own. Or probably use another alternative like Hazelcast.

Comment: I am using dynacache on my servers, however just to prove hashmap was easily breakable I brewed my own test. I feel my issue is caching a hashmap of <String, String> as a single cache entry within dynacache, where as I should add each of my string keys as a dynacache entry in their own right

Comment: Maybe [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) (concurrent analog of `HashMap`)?

Comment: Will concurrentHashMap work when cached in dynacache across multiple nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All my issues were solved by simply changing my use of HashMap() to ConcurrentHashMap().